# Twitch API - Fail in the user request

Tags: php, curl, twitch

Everything in the PHP code is correct (I checked myself) and there is no error from curl, but the result is always an empty variable (No true/false).

```
public function prepareUser() {
$url = $this->TwitchAPI->endUrl("USERT");
$temp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($temp, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($temp, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($temp, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Authorization" => "OAuth " . $this->access_token));
curl_setopt($temp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($temp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$ret = curl_exec($temp);
if (curl_errno($temp)) {
die("Error - " . curl_error($temp));
}
curl_close($temp);

$this->user = json_decode($ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone and everyone can use this interface as a platform to grab information from Twitch and post information to Twitch.  All needed information is provided on the GIT itself, and is available with only 1 restriction, that you not redistribute the platform (For several security reasons).  The GIT is also a good way to get help when needed, as I check it daily.  Enjoy and have fun deving!

https://github.com/IBurn36360/Twitch_Interface